# How to access data after mistakenly partition changed from NTFS to Ext4?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ext4, data-loss

Recently, I was trying to install Ubuntu on my Laptop.Laptop Specifications are as follow:
Dell Inspiron 15 3000
HardDisk: 1Tb
RAM 4GB

During the ubuntu installation process, there was a step when we need a partition to allocate space to ubuntu .I had mistakenly changed the partition type to Ext4 from NTFS while shrinking volume of that drive. I then realized my mistake and returned back to windows to see if there was an effect on my partition. In windows, that partition was not displaying any more. Then i run the Ubuntu Live from USB Disk and see if i could see the partition from Ubuntu. The Ubuntu OS is displaying that partition and used/avaialble space also. But upon opening the drive i couldn't see any data. The partition is showing my previously used space and available space but not displaying any kind of data. I even tried to see hidden data but still no luck. 
Need Help!
Thanks.

Comment: You're being misled a bit because you are using the wrong term. "Change" from A to B sounds like you can "change" back. However, what you really describe is *reformatting* your partition to use a new filesystem. Formatting (and reformatting) deletes all data permanently. Use the Search box at the top of the page to look up how to use "data-recovery" tools to try and recover some of your data. You may find it a frustrating and tedious process. Installing an OS and disk partitioning are inherently risky - backups before you begin are wise.

Comment: @user535733 Yes you are right! but still i see the used space in my reformated partion in ubuntu live from USB disk means its still there. but i cant see the data. is there any way i can read the data from ubuntu somhow?

Comment: Start with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery. Warning: Using the overwritten partition lets the system overwrite it even more. More data loss every minute.

Comment: @user535733 okay if i change back my partition type to NTFS from windows disk management, will i still be able to recover my lost data using any recovery tool?

Comment: No: All the metadata (what the files were called, which blocks the files were stored in, etc.) was erased when you reformatted. Reformating *again* will merely reduce the likelihood of recovering anything at all. Again, mis-referring to a reformat as a mere "change" is leading you down an unwise path.